# How to redirect an entire sub-directory path to a new sub-directory path in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite and I cannot get it to redirect anything containing `wp-content/uploads` by replacing it with `wp-content/blogs.dir/23/files/sites/23` for my certain sub-domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my.example.com$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /wp-content/blogs.dir/23/files/sites/23/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I get an Internal Server Error

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried removing both of your `RewriteCond` and just leave the `RewriteRule` by itself? Your `RewriteRule` appears perfect! Checkout https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=46cba271-fc09-5fd3-8fd9-7e199bcc5cb0 and look at the "Output url" section to ensure that that URL is exactly as you wanted, as it is a bit of a strange one!

Comment: I can't take out the rewrite condition because this is a virtual host server running other hosts and this rule would adversely impact other sites.